# Как переслать сообщения пользователя бота другому человеку?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

[image]
#На картинке, при нажатии на кнопку другое, высвечивается сообщение с кнопкой "Готово". Пользователь должен ввести необходимую информацию о мелодии, которую хочет. затем пользователь нажимает кнопку готово. После чего, сообщение пользователя должно *переслаться* мне (для проверки работоспособности программы) а так *композитору*. Однако, бот пересылает свое же сообщение, а не пользовательское. Вот и вопрос в том, что нужно сделать, чтобы пересылалось сообщение пользователя.

```
to_chat_id = "айди кому отправить сообщение"

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_message(call):

    ...

    elif call.data == 'other':
        quest_stage21(call.message)
    elif call.data == 'done':
        quest_stage22(call.message)
    return

def quest_stage21(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    st21btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Готово', 
callback_data='done')
    markup.row(st21btn1)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напишите, пожалуйста, в одно сообщение следующее: направление (минус, бит, грув и т.д.), стиль выбранного направления, темп мелодии, характер мелодии, разнообразный ли должен быть продукт (нет, разнообразный, умеренный).', reply_markup=markup)



def quest_stage22(message):
    bot.forward_message(to_chat_id, message.chat.id, message.from_user.id)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: Это нужно для того, чтобы человек, которому нужна мелодия, написал что он хочет, и это сообщение автоматом отправлялось композитору в лс

Comment: как понять присылает сообщение бота? Добавьте код, который есть у вас сейчас, в вопрос

Comment: Уважаемые кодеры, мне очень нужна ваша помощь, у меня дедлайн последний день

Comment: Ну так поясните, что работает не так? Какое поведение бота ожидается и что работает не так? И что значит присылает сообщение бота?

Comment: @CausonQ фото добавил, проблему пояснил, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Для чего вообще эта кнопка "Готово"? Судя по коду, текст от пользователя и эта кнопка между собой никак не связаны. И получается так: Жмем другое, показываем сообщение с кнопкой, пользователь пише текст и отправляет его боту, а при нажатии на кнопку готово, бот знать не знает про сообщение, которое написал пользователь. Кроме того, при нажатии готово, боту передается id сообщения, к которому прилеплена сама кнопка. По-этому, он и пересылает свое сообщение

Comment: В вашем случае, это простейший бот обратной связи. Я бы использовал fsm: Жмем "Другое", пользователю отправляем сообщение, что бы он написал и отправил требуемую информацию, а в боте устанавливаем стэйт и ждем сообщение. Пользователь отправляет свое сообщение и его пересылаем, без доп кнопки Готово

Comment: Или, если нужно непременно использовать кнопу готово, то нужно куда-то записывать id сообщения от пользователи и передавать его в forward_message

Comment: Спасибо огромное, выручили!!!

Comment: @CausonQ Однако, вы не могли бы написать пару строчек кода, со стейтом, а то не знаю как им пользоваться...

Comment: Нет, не смогу. Я работаю с aiogram

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте пересылать сообщения ни через forward а сохранить его в переменную и передать ее а далее отправить на id админа

например:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "отправте текст")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, text)
    
def text(message):
    text = message.text
    
    bot.send_message('ид пользователя', text=text)
```